# TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not an User nor a Role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I got this error: **(node:11624) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not an User nor a Role.**

This my code:

```js
const sr = message.guild.roles.cache.get(supportrole)
const everyone = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "@everyone")

c.updateOverwrite(sr, {
    SEND_MESSAGE: true,
    VIEW_CHANNEL: true
});

c.updateOverwrite(everyone, {
    SEND_MESSAGE: false,
    VIEW_CHANNEL: false
});

c.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
    SEND_MESSAGE: true,
    VIEW_CHANNEL: true
});
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```js
const everyone = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "@everyone")
```

Is the problem. You will not be able to find a role in those conditions. Fun fact, the @everyone role shares the same ID as the guild it's in. So, you can instead use:

```js
const everyone = message.guild.roles.cache.get(message.guild.id)
```